# Auto redirect Cloudflare protected site to ifastnet.com by Using infinityfree hosting

Tags: dns, add-on-domain

My username and others detail of my id is shown below (**Username** **epiz_27970030**):

[image]

I have bought one domain by the name of `http://vip42.ir/`
and I am trying to add this domain to the **infinityfree** account (`http://painting-persta.rf.gd`)

So I have tried to change the Cloudflare NS setting to desired setting as you can see below:
[image]

***###The Error Message***

As you can see below, I can not add domain to the :
https://cpanel.epizy.com/panel/indexpl.php?option=error

By selecting **Addon Domains** option, as you can see below, I get the below error:

> Error Adding Domain..

[image]

Also, I have tried the Cloudflare setting and get this error, as you can see below:
[image]

> CLOUDFLARE ERROR : We were unable to identify painting-persta.rf.gd as
> a registered domain. Please ensure you are providing the root domain
> and not any subdomains (e.g., example.com, not subdomain.example.com)

The domain is redirecting to this site :
[image]

https://ifastnet.com
Or
http://suspended-website.com/

So I want to know, I must wait until 72 hours or have to do something to fix this problem (redirecting to the `http://suspended-website.com` or `https://ifastnet.com`!).

**Update:**

based of [this](https://forum.infinityfree.net/t/cloudflare-ns-ns1-epizy-com-and-ns1-byet-org-redirect-to-http-suspended-website-com/41940/2) answer:

> Please change your domain nameservers to ns1.epizy.com and
> ns2.epizy.com in order to add your domain, after you parked your
> domain through parked domains section in VPanel, change your
> nameservers back to the cloudflare ones.

Firstly, I have changed the domain NS setting as you can see below:
[image]
so by trying to add domain I get this error:
[image]

And by trying to park the domain I get the error has been shown below:
[image]

So, I guess I must wait for almost 72 Hrs, for **DNS Updating**, am I right?

**Update 2:**

Thanks, The **parking Domain**, has been updated almost after 1 Hr :
[image]
During this time I have changed the DNS Setting of domain, to :

- ns1.epizy.com
- ns2.epizy.com
  **and**
- ns1.byet.org
- ns2.byet.org

as you can see below:
[image]

So I don't know, it works because of adding This DNS (**ns1.byet.org** and **ns2.byet.org**)  ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you register the domain `vip42.ir`?    What are the name server (NS) DNS records for it at your registry?

Comment: Have you tried to add `vip42.ir` to Cloudflare instead of adding `painting-persta.rf.gd` to Cloudflare?

Comment: Thanks, **@Stephen_Ostermiller**, I updated question and add the `vip42.ir` domain registration Information at question.

Comment: "So, I guess I must wait for almost 72 Hrs, for DNS Updating, am I right?" No, there is no DNS propagation or hardcoded times. If you do changes on authoritative nameservers they are live "immediately".

Answer (score 1):

I think I have this straight:

- Your domain registrar is IRNIC
- Your web hosting company is IFastNet (rf.gd)
- You want to use Cloudflare for CDN

I'm not sure how epizy or beyt fit into the picture.

### Set `NS` records *only* at your domain registrar

The first thing to know is that you should only ever set `NS` records at your domain registrar.   The only place you should be setting `NS` records is at IRNIC.  You shouldn't ever try to set NS records at CloudFlare, or IFastNet.   Doing so will have no effect.   If you have set `NS` records at any of these places, you should delete them.

### Only use *one* company's name servers at a time

Your `NS` records specify the company that is going to DNS host.   You usually have some choice about which company is going to host your DNS.  It can usually be either your domain registrar or your web host.   However, it would be very unusual to have `NS` records pointing to two different DNS hosts.  You should only have `NS` records pointing to one DNS hosting company.

Using two companies for DNS hosting could work, but it would be a pain and I wouldn't recommend it.  You would have to keep all your `A`, `CNAME`, `TXT`, `MX` and other records synced and up to date between two different companies.   If you use just one company, they will update all their name servers with your records when you update them on their website.

### Setting up Cloudflare

If you use Cloudflare, they will want to be your DNS host.   They will require that you point your `NS` records to them for their service to work.

If you want to use CloudFlare as a CDN:

1. Remove all the `NS` records you tried to set at CloudFlare
2. Change your `NS` records at IRNIC to `kate.ns.cloudflare.com` and `brad.ns.cloudflare.com` as suggested by cloudflare in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1XwI.png
3. Set up proxied CNAME records at CloudFlare for `vip42.ir` and `www.vip42.ir` pointing to `painting-persta.rf.gd`.

You shouldn't need to:

- Add `vip42.ir` to your web hosting account
- Use the nameservers from epizy or byet.

Continue to use your hosting account with subdomain they give you.

You may have to wait 72 hours for all the changes to take effect, but it usually happens significantly faster than that.

Comment: Thanks it have been solved by changing the `NS` setting of the Main domain registration site ( `IRNIC`) to web host DNS setting + saving the `vip42.ir` domain to addone Domain part of web host cPanel. And after that I changed the `IRNIC` DNS setting to Cloudflare `NS` again. Now by inserting the ٰ`vip42.ir` in browser I get the listing page, which is better from before (but there is some problem with the site codes =PrestaShop) which I asked [here](https://forum.infinityfree.net/t/cloudflare-ns-ns1-epizy-com-and-ns1-byet-org-redirect-to-http-suspended-website-com/41940/7)